# Cocoapods duplicate symbol - Google APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoapods, google-api-client

I've performed `pod update` 2 days ago, everything went with success, I could build the project. Log:

```
Removing DTAlertView
Downloading dependencies
Using GTMHTTPFetcher (0.1.0)
Using Google-API-Client (0.1.1)
Using Google-Maps-iOS-SDK (1.9.0)
Using KissXML (5.0)
Using MGSwipeTableCell (1.3.3)
Installing RNBlurModalView (0.1.0)
Using gtm-oauth2 (0.1.0)
Using iVersion (1.11.4)
Using libextobjc (0.4.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

Now I had to perform `pod update` again, however now I can't build the project. Log:

```
Removing RNBlurModalView
Downloading dependencies
Installing GTMHTTPFetcher 1.141 (was 0.1.0)
Using Google-API-Client (0.1.1)
Installing Google-Maps-iOS-SDK 1.9.1 (was 1.9.0)
Using KissXML (5.0)
Installing MGSwipeTableCell 1.3.5 (was 1.3.3)
Installing gtm-http-fetcher (1.0.141)
Installing gtm-oauth2 1.0.125 (was 0.1.0)
Using iVersion (1.11.4)
Using libextobjc (0.4.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] GTMHTTPFetcher has been deprecated in favor of gtm-http-fetcher
```

I need to complete one feature today and my project doesn't build. What to do to at least enable it to build? `pod install` doesn't help. I've noticed that probably version jump of `Google-Maps-iOS-SDK` made the whole mess with `GTMHTTPFetcher`, so I've tried to set in podfile version 1.9.0:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'libextobjc', '~> 0.4'
pod 'KissXML', '~> 5.0'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '1.9.0'
pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 0.1'
pod 'MGSwipeTableCell', '~> 1.0'
pod 'iVersion', '~> 1.10'
```

But it doesn't help. Probably Google-api-client is incompatible with Google maps, because if I remove google api:

```
Removing GTMHTTPFetcher
Removing Google-API-Client
Removing gtm-http-fetcher
Removing gtm-oauth2
Downloading dependencies
Installing Google-Maps-iOS-SDK (1.9.1)
Using KissXML (5.0)
Using MGSwipeTableCell (1.3.5)
Using iVersion (1.11.4)
Using libextobjc (0.4.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

And probably it would work (can't try, many connections from the code). The errors:

```
[... many more of same type as below ...]
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMReadMonitorInputStream in:
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-cvbrvhbcpumxaohhjabqvxiyzotr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-GTMHTTPFetcher.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-cvbrvhbcpumxaohhjabqvxiyzotr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-gtm-http-fetcher.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
ld: 163 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Neither clean nor deleting derived data doesn't help.

Comment: I've accepted @PeterSegerblom answer, but in fact it is only tmp solution (thank you, i needed such tmp solution!). I have no idea how to fix it long-term. I also have no idea why it happened today, when I've made update 2 days ago and everything was working fine while last commit of gtm services pod spec repo was a month ago.

Comment: I've submited an issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/detail?id=82&thanks=82&ts=1422007572, as I think it may be their bug. Less probably something got messed up with my cocoapods installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as an updated answer.

From post of @peter-segerblom, I've noticed that in fact `GTMHTTPFetcher` is an older version of `gtm-http-fetcher`. Because of compability issues, I couldn't update `Google-API-Client`. Temporary workaround was to:

1. Open `~/.cocoapods/repos`
2. Delete `gtm-oauth2` (>= 1.0.125)
3. Delete `gtm-http-fetcher` (whole)
4. Delete `GTMHTTPFetcher` (> 0.1.0)

However atm, all of us need to update the libraries to use bitcode, as the project won't even build in the new Xcode. Because of this, I've updated my code and changed version from:

```
pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 0.1'
```

to:

```
pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 1.0'
```

Now only waiting for Google to update the lib to bitcode requirements, as with new `Google-API-Client` everything is working properly and we don't need to do these hacks with deleting from `.cocoapods/repos`.

Comment: This just causes more errors....its damn close to a year later, how can such a rich company be so shitty?

Comment: @ChuckKelly Are you sure you've updated to at least 1.0 version? Can you paste the console output during the upload?

Answer (score 2):

I met this case and already resolved it.
Open two configuraton files of Pod 
Pods-your_app_name.debug.xcconfig
Pods-your_app_name.release.xcconfig
then removing anything which is related to "GTMHTTPFetcher". Clean and build again. It will work fine. 
This solution is not best solution so far. Because everytime you run command "pod install", GTMHTTPFetcher will be installed automatically and you (include me) have to follow steps above to remove again. Anyway here is unique solution for me until now.

Comment: Well, that's also a way, however using the one I've described above in comments you need to perform once per many infinity instead of each install. Disadvantage is that it's global, so other projects also won't see `gtm-http-fetcher`. Shame on Google to have such easy bug and not fix it for so long!

Answer (score 0):

These two look too be the same thing?

```
Installing gtm-http-fetcher (1.0.141)
Installing GTMHTTPFetcher 1.141 (was 0.1.0)
```

And since the error is duplicate symbols in the linker I would try removing one of them.

Comment: I can't remove one of them. One is used by google maps, second one by google api... I don't download them directly, take a look into my podfile.

Comment: Oh yeah, does it work if you put both of the google pods to :head ?

Comment: No, I was mistaken, both of these are used by google api - I've updated my question, when I remove google api both are deinstalled. Did they made a mistake..? I didn't see google api version bump, why did it change at all? :/.

Comment: [!] Error installing Google-API-Client
[!] /usr/bin/svn export --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --force "http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk//trunk" /Users/username/company/project/Pods/Google-API-Client

svn: E170000: URL 'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk' doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry i'm lost.. Did you try :head? Also maybe check The Google-api Podspec file to see what dependencies it lists. And if you just want to build quick today maybe you could remove the duplicate dependency manually from the Podspec file. it should be in ~/.cocoapods/repos

Comment: Also as you can see the GTMHTTPFetcher was at version 0.1.0 but now 1.141 while the gym-http-fetcher always was 1.0.141. Looks incredibly suspicious too me :)

Comment: Yes, I've tried head and pasted the output above - it's the error I've received when I've tried :head. Won't removing it harm the references from google-api-client (https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google-API-Client/1.0.418/Google-API-Client.podspec.json)? if they've referenced it from podspec, probably they use it in code. I'll try your advice.

Comment: To your last comment: gtm-http-fetcher was not installed previously, it was added after today's update. I've removed from ~/.cocoapods/repos: gtm-oauth2 (1.0.125), gtm-http-fetcher (whole), GTMHTTPFetcher (everything above 0.1.0) and it's working.

Comment: You removed those folders from ~/.cocoapods/repos and did pod install again or did you do anything else on the Xcode project?

Comment: @EmersonMalca I've removed these folders and performed `pod update`, as `pod install` will only install selected, and we want the `.lock` to be updated.